# Blank Icon on Dash/Favorites bar

Tags: unity, icons, steam

When I launch a steam game called "The Binding of Isaac", and its running and open the Icon on the sidebar/dash/favorites (I'm not sure what its called) is blank i tried verifying the install from steam i tried restarting but it doesn't fix it.  I saw another post on here about this [Unity launcher and Steam icons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855156/unity-launcher-and-steam-icons)

I also tried that it doesn't help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If no icon is found, a generic icon should be shown. That now you see a "black" icon leads me to suspect that there could be an issue with the icon referred to in the .desktop launcher you are showing in the linked image.

Thus, locate the icon file and check it. It should have an extension `.png` or `.ico` or `.svg`.

To create your own icon, create a hidden folder `.icons` or `.local/share/icons` in your home folder, and put a valid .png or .svg icon graphic in the folder. Then that one will be used.

Comment: I checked the file and searched for the file which is linked, it is in fact a .png in the ~/.local/share/icons folder.  The icon appears on the desktop its only when it is running on the favorites/dash bar that its blank/black  (see the attached image to see icon on desktop fine but on dash bar incorrectly)